# Gibbs equation and reversibility

Tags: thermodynamics, reversibility

The equation 
$$TdS=dU+PdV$$
is a combination of 
$$dQ=dU+PdV$$
and 
$$TdS=dQ.$$
But in some process that is very irreversible, $TdS>dQ$, should we write 
$$TdS>dU+PdV$$
instead of the first equation? I guess the equation is different for reversible and irreversible process.